# Multiple error messages displayed on a angularJS model

Tags: java, html, angularjs

I'm currently interested in implementing a modal with the possibility to view multiple error messages or the ability to retrieve a list of IDs from my method on the back-end and display it for the front-end.

```
if (value.getId().equals(valueService.getId())) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Value with provided id '%s' is currently entitled to another entity with ID '%s'", ...));
}
```

Currently my application can throw an error message if it finds the comparison to be at fault once, however I would like it so that multiple error messages can be carried out with each one being listed on the front end in a modal view.

My code listed under is the front end which contains the modal view that I want to have with these error messages listed on.

ANGULAR JS:

```
function (response) {
                $uibModal.open({
                    windowClass: "lg",
                    templateUrl: "...",
                    controller: '...',
                    backdrop: 'static',
                    resolve: {
                    }
                }).result.then(function (response) {
                    if (response === true) {
                    }
                })
            }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h3 class="modal-title">Title</h3>
    <p>Blah blah</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">

</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <h4>Save these changes?</h4>
    <button class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="closeAndSave()">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-blue" ng-click="closeModal()">No</button>
</div>
```

Yes I know the response is not linked with my model view at all, but I'm not too sure how to proceed. Which solution would be better to implement? A table in the modal which lists out all the ids which are found in that if statement, if so, how can that be achieved? Or throwing multiple error messages and then somehow listing it on the modal view. I hope that is enough info provided, if more is needed, can provide.

Comment: Just build an Array with your errors messages and pass it to the modal to be render. In the modal you can use a table a list or any prefered way to display it.

Comment: Hello, could you submit an answer. Sounds good.